# Bootstrap-3 grid layout and a fixed sized ad banner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

While reading about the new grid system of bootstrap I asked myself, how do ad banners fit into such grid systems?

I am aware of responsive ads (ad sense, etc) but I still do not understand how those concepts apply to a skyscraper ad banner properly.

Here is a mock of what I am talking about:
[image: Mock of an ad]

Having a horizontal ad is fine but how does bootstrap help me to create such a layout?
Hiding the skyscraper for small devices is no problem, using grid helpers, but am I right, that I still need to mess with `float: left;` and `clearfix` for such a scenario?

Even if the skyscraper would be responsive and resize itself according to some column width, e.g `col-md-2`, etc, it still would require some sort of "row span" in order to span arbitrary rows.

**Edit:** just to make it clear: I am not asking for a complete markup all-dressed up, just for insights whether such a concept is outdated in responsive times or that this is still something for `float: right` or `position: relative` etc.

Comment: @sdcr I don't think that calc will help me here. I am lacking the concept of integrating something that "vertical" into a row/col based responsive design. Runtime calc of available sizes via media queries, calc or js are not my main issue here.

Comment: did you want the container off center. why not contain everything and then have a column 11 to for the main section and col 1 for the add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap isn't designed to have a fixed width column.  It is designed around percentage column widths.

However, you can use create media queries that follow Bootstrap's use of them.  For "tablet" sized devices, Bootstrap sets the overall container to fixed width of 768px, like below.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width:750px
    }
}
```

You can make use of this knowledge to create two classes that divide the layout into two columns.  One for with of content and one for the ads.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-left-width{
    width: 625px;
  }
  .col-right-width{
    width: 120px;
  }
}
```

This allows you to have a fixed right column width of 120px.  But as the size of the screen changes, you can redefine the "left" column width to

```
Container Width - 120 - Padding.
```

In this case, the left column would be set to 625px.

I have a working sample at http://jsbin.com/suceji/3/